# Dynamic modification of SVG with Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm trying to dynamically modify an SVG document embedded in an html page, so I may add a decorator when some event happens (e.g., a button is pressed).

To do that, I first insert the decorator image into the "defs" element of the SVG during "onload", to later add a "use" element into an SVG group during the occurrence of the event. The code seems to add (in Firefox) both the image element during onload, and the use element when the event happens, but the decorator image is not displayed. If I persist the same SVG document, it is correctly displayed by all browsers.

Let me show you a simplified code. Here is a jsfiddle, thanks to Phrogz: http://jsfiddle.net/ewYkp/3/

Imagine this html page:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <title>Dynamic Modification of SVG demo</title>
  <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <script language="javascript">
   var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
   function setOnLoad()
   {
    var svg = document.getElementById("SVG_IMAGE").contentDocument;
    defs = svg.getElementsByTagName("defs");
    def1 = defs[0];
    var imageNote = document.SVG_IMAGE.contentDocument.createElementNS(svgns,"image");
    imageNote.setAttribute("width","22");
    imageNote.setAttribute("height","22");
    imageNote.setAttribute("id","noteImage");
     imageNote.setAttribute("xlink:href","data:image/png;base64,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");
     def1.appendChild(imageNote);
    };

    function decorateSVG() {
     var svg = document.getElementById("SVG_IMAGE");
     var dElement = svg.contentDocument.getElementById("group1");
 var useNote = svg.contentDocument.createElementNS(svgns,"use");
 useNote.setAttribute("x","150");
 useNote.setAttribute("y","150");
 useNote.setAttribute("xlink:href","#noteImage");
 dElement.appendChild(useNote);
    };
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1>Dynamic Modification of SVG demo - embed svg file with SVG image</h1>
   <p> A  yellow circle that was embeded using the svg "object" tag</p>
    <object id="SVG_IMAGE" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"  data="basic_shapes_circle1.svg" width="400" y="0" x="0" type="image/svg+xml" onload="setOnLoad()">
    </object>
   <p>
    <button onclick="decorateSVG('circle')">Decorate circle </button>
   </p>
  <hr>
 </body>
</html>
```

and the following svg document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <defs>
  <!-- A circle of radius 200 -->
  <circle id="s1" cx="200" cy="200" r="200" fill="yellow" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
 </defs>
 <g id="group1">
    <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#s1"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

The code (supposedly) results is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <defs>
  <!-- A circle of radius 200 -->
  <circle id="s1" cx="200" cy="200" r="200" fill="yellow" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
  <image width="22" height="22" id="noteImage" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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"/>
</defs>
<g id="group1">
  <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#s1"/>
  <use x="150" y="150" xlink:href="#noteImage"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

If you save the SVG document into a file, it displays correctly in any browser.
However, it doesn't seem to work when modified in memory, and I can't figure out why.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Here's a simplified JSFiddle showing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/ewYkp/3/

Comment: Great, thanks! and sorry about that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are not setting the `xlink:href` attributes properly. You are doing this:

```
someElement.setAttribute( "xlink:href", "…" );
```

Doing that creates an attribute named "xlink:href" (an invalid name) with no namespace. Instead, you want to be using:

```
someElement.setAttributeNS( "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "href", "…");
```

Here's a working demo, showing that this works whether you add the dynamically-created image directly to the group, or place it in the `<defs>` section and reference it via a `<use>`:

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ewYkp/4/

---

BTW, for convenience and to save your wrists, I recommend a little function like this:

```
function createOn( dad, name, attrs, text ){
  var svg = dad.ownerSVGElement, doc = dad.ownerDocument;
  var ns = createOn.$NAMESPACES;
  var defaultNS = svg.namespaceURI;
  if (!ns){
    ns = createOn.$NAMESPACES = {};
    for (var a=svg.attributes,i=a.length;i--;) if (a[i].prefix=='xmlns') ns[a[i].localName] = a[i].nodeValue;
  }
  var p = name.split(':');
  var el = p[1] ? doc.createElementNS(ns[p[0]],p[1]) : doc.createElementNS(defaultNS,name);
  for (var a in attrs){
    p = a.split(':');
    if (p[1]) el.setAttributeNS(ns[p[0]],p[1],attrs[a]);
    else      el.setAttributeNS(null,a,attrs[a]);
  }
  if (text) el.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(text));
  return dad.appendChild(el);
}
```

Use it like so:

```
var defs = svgDoc.querySelector('defs');
var img  = createOn(defs,'image',{
  x:100, y:150,
  width:22, height:22,
  id:'noteImage', 'xlink:href':data
});
```

It will automatically look up the namespace prefix for the element name or attribute name as long as the prefix matches a namespace declared on the owning document. Here's an updated demo using that:

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ewYkp/6/

Comment: Phrogz, you nailed it. Thanks a lot!